# How do I edit react code of components like mui directly? No customization, just react code

Tags: reactjs

I want to edit mui components, and see how they were written in react? Not customize it. Just direct editing. It would make it much easier to see how these components are written in react themselves and change tiny bits. Thanks!

Comment: Personalising a UI library like that means you lose the primary reasons to use that library: consistency, reusability and familiarity between projects. If you just want to look at how it's built, check out their source code on GitHub, but please don't leave a "slightly modified and impossible to upgrade MUI" copy in your projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material ui components are open source. You can see their source code in github: https://github.com/mui/material-ui

If you want to edit them, you can clone the repo, follow the steps to setup your environment and try changing the code.
You could also open github codespaces on the repository, which i find to be a really useful tool for inspecting source code quickly.